# Vec3f class in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, macos, vector

just a quick question.

I want to make a 3d game in OpenGL on a Mac but I'm not sure how to make a Vec3f class in objective c.

I would really like to be able to set the class like,

```
    Vec3f *point = {1,2,3};
```

but still be able to treat it like a class.

The only I things can think of is use a typedef struct or use regular objc setters like

```
    -(void)setX:(int)X{ x = X; }
```

I don't know. Any Suggestions.

EDIT: Just to be clear I want to be able to set the class as if it was an array. I don't need to know how to make the class, I just want to be able to know how to set the class with curly braces. Thank you.

Comment: I know it's not the answer to your question, but for performance you will be better off sticking to an array or struct of floats for this. If you look at any Apple example openGL code you won't find a Vec4f Class.

Comment: Realized a couple of days ago that I can cast the array as a struct. I made a header file with a bunch of inline functions(kinda copied the CGPoint header that Apple made). I can then set it by 'Vec3f vector = (Vec3f){x,y,z};'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this in Obj-C. It doesn't provide any mechanism to do alternant initialization like that. Your best bet is to do something like this...

```
+ (id)generateVector:(float[3])vec;
{
  //set internal structure
}

[Vec3f generateVector:{1,2,3}];
```

Comment: Thanks, I just thought that I would ask because I know an NSString can be set by `= @"text"`